# Time Capsule on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macbook, time-machine

I use Time Machine to backup my MacBook Pro. Everything works fine.

My girlfriend has a PC with Windows 7 installed. She wants to backup her PC with Cobian Backup on Time Machine, but her PC doesn't see Time Capsule, so it's impossible to connect.

Time Capsule, PC and MacBook Pro are all connected to my ADSL using WiFi.

Why doesn't Windows see the Time Capsule? I installed Bonjour service on Windows 7, but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Apparently, `Windows 8` is going to include a `Time Capsule`-like backup program.

Answer (score 1):

[Genie Timeline Professional](http://www.genie-soft.com/Business/genie_timeline_pro/overview.aspx) can do this for you in an even better way than Time Capsule does,
it can't see the Time Capsule though so you'll need a external hard drive or network drive to back-up to.

**EDIT:**

You can try [Using Cobian Backup on Windows with Apple's Time Capsule](http://blog.gerke-preussner.de/2009/08/using-cobian-backup-on-windows-with-apples-time-capsule/).

If that doesn't work, here are my thoughts:

> You are mixing up MS stuff with *nix stuff and are looking for problems by just doing that. The best hope you can go for is to check if the Time Capsule can be configured to enable Windows Sharing (Samba), and even if you do have that backing up won't work perfectly and will be slow or you might even not have write permissions to it. Also note that the size management of the Time Capsule will work less well than expected. One car can drive on Diesel, the other one will need LPG...

Comment: I don't want to buy an external disk. Why windows doesn't see the TC, it's my question. Is a network problem ?
The software uses to do backup is an item.

Comment: Reply for your edit:

I found it on google but after the handling, windows doesn't see the TC :(

Comment: I have added a link to a guide that might help you out, if it doesn't then I can't help you further... I have previously experienced the effect of how bad backing up over NTFS <--> WiFi --> EXT2/3 works, it goes slow and you'll encounter permission problems.

Comment: I can't help you more than this, I can believe that it could work and not have the issues I had, good luck... Hopefully someone will hop in that does have that working or you might find another solution somewhere else, but if not... Genie Timeline comes the closest to the way Time Capsule works and is according to it's listed features even better. Indeed, it costs money, so sticking with a program you already have is probably a better option. However, good luck on securing her data... :-)